# How can i fix bootstrap row column empty area problem?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, row, col

Nowadays, I am developing a simple web app but i have problem about bootstrap row and column.

This is my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Col-1</p>
         <p>Col-1</p>
         <p>Col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Col-2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Col-3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Col-4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Col-5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Col-6</p>
    </div>
```

And this is my web app scrennshot
[image]

I want to remove white empty area but i don't know what can i do with bootstrap?

I am waiting your advices and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. If you have a same problem please use this library.
[Masonry Library](https://masonry.desandro.com/)